# Required validation in input field if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a from in which, some checkboxes and related that checkboxes, input fields is present. If i select any checkbox then inputfield appears and then I have to fill that input field. If do not fill input field, which checkbox is checked then **required** message should be show.

My code is:

```
  <form id="submit_form" action="#" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
  <?php 
  $result = $obj->show_social_icons();
  foreach($result as $key => $row)
  {
  ?>
   <div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 heightauto">
    <input type="checkbox" class="maxtickets_enable_cb" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['checkbox']) && ($_SESSION['checkbox'] != '')) { if(in_array($row['id'],$_SESSION['checkbox'])) {?> checked="checked" <?php } else{ echo ""; } }?> name="opwp_wootickets[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?>

     <div class="max_tickets">
      <input type="text" name="link[]" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['link']) && ($_SESSION['link'] != '')) { echo $_SESSION['link'][$key]; } ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $row['placeholder']; ?>" class="form-control validatethis">
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
   <button type="submit" href="#" name="social_submit" class="next_button">Preview</button>
   </form>
```

jquery is:

```
 $('form#submit_form').on('submit', function(event) {
$('.validatethis').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", 
        {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "This field is required",
            }
        });
});
});
$("#submit_form").validate();
```

[image]

Validation applied only on first row. In above code, if I filled first checkbox input field and again check other checkbox and empty that inputfield then form submits. How to apply validation in all checked checkboxes input field?

Comment: Show the rendered HTML.  This plugin depends on the markup to be constructed correctly.  How are we supposed to replicate the JavaScript without the actual markup your JavaScript is using?

Comment: FYI - the plugin depends on the `name` being unique.  Validation only on first row means that your names are the same on all the rows.  The plugin needs `name[0]`, `name[1]`, etc. and cannot handle `name[]` array without the index key.  In your PHP loop, insert an index key into the array.

Comment: Finally, adding the rules within a submit event handler makes no sense.  Add them immediately after the fields are created.

Comment: @Sparky Thankyou for reply. But I am confused how to do that. Can U please share some code?

Comment: Please click on the link for duplicate above your question.